# How to access Azure blob using SAS in C#

Tags: rest, azure, blob

When I am trying to create / access Azure blob using Ad-hoc Shared Access Signature (SAS) I am getting "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden." error.  Can someone help me to identify, what is going wrong with this code.

```
    // Calling this function from Main().
    public void uploadToBlob()
    {
        string content = "Hello World - Content of the file";
        string fileName = "TestFile";
        UploadFileToAzureBlobStorage(content, fileName);
    }

    void UploadFileToAzureBlobStorage(string content, string fileName)
    {
        string storageKey = "SAS Key";
        string storageAccount = "Storage Account name";
        string containerName = "Container Name";
        string blobName = fileName;

        string method = "PUT";
        string sampleContent = content;
        int contentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(sampleContent);

        string requestUri = $"https://{storageAccount}.blob.core.windows.net/{containerName}/{blobName}";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
        string now = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R");
        request.Method = method;
        request.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
        request.ContentLength = contentLength;
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2015-12-11");
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", now);
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", AuthorizationHeader(method, now, request, storageAccount, storageKey, containerName, blobName));

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sampleContent), 0, contentLength);
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            { }
        }
    }

    public string AuthorizationHeader(string method, string now, HttpWebRequest request, string storageAccount, string storageKey, string containerName, string blobName)
    {
        string headerResource = $"x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:{now}\nx-ms-version:2015-12-11";
        string urlResource = $"/{storageAccount}/{containerName}/{blobName}";
        string stringToSign = $"{method}\n\n\n{request.ContentLength}\n\n{request.ContentType}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{headerResource}\n{urlResource}";
        HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(storageKey));
        string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));
        String AuthorizationHeader = String.Format("{0} {1}:{2}", "SharedKey", storageAccount, signature);
        return AuthorizationHeader;
    }
```

Comment: For storage key, are you using account key or SAS token?

Comment: Also, do you have the response headers?

Comment: @Guaurav Mantri, I am passing SAS token here.

Comment: @Cam Soper, Here is the response :AuthenticationFailedServer failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:d4af7fcf-001e-0041-7532-4127e3000000 Time:2017-10-09T19:10:06.7310979ZRequest date header too old: 'Mon, 09 Oct 2017 17:40:52 GMT'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you're using above is needed when you're using an account key. This is when you would need to compute and include `Authorization` header in your request. If you're using a `Shared Access Signature (SAS)` token, you don't need to do all of this because SAS token already includes authorization information.

Assuming your SAS Token is valid and contain appropriate permissions to upload a file, your code becomes quite simple. Please see modified code below:

```
void UploadFileToAzureBlobStorage(string content, string fileName)
{
    string sasToken = "SAS Key";
    string storageAccount = "Storage Account name";
    string containerName = "Container Name";
    string blobName = fileName;

    string method = "PUT";
    string sampleContent = content;
    int contentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(sampleContent);

    string requestUri = $"https://{storageAccount}.blob.core.windows.net/{containerName}/{blobName}?{sasToken}";

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
    request.Method = method;
    request.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
    request.ContentLength = contentLength;
    request.Headers.Add("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");

    using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        requestStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sampleContent), 0, contentLength);
    }

    using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        { }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm, thanks Gaurav for suggesting it!!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this would work directly because I changed some things besides the connectionstring. But maybe it will help.

Note that in this case I am returning the path of the image with header defined, because it is unnecessary to download the image to the server, it is better to deliver directly to the client.

```
    public static string ChaveStringConexao { get; set; }        


    public static string ObterUrlTemporaria(string container, string nomeBlob, string nomeOriginal, bool paraDownload = false)
    {
        var blob = InstanciaContainer(container).GetBlockBlobReference(nomeBlob);
        var sasToken = string.Empty;

        var sasPolicy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy
        {
            Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
            SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-15),
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30)
        };

        var _sasHeader = new SharedAccessBlobHeaders
        {
            ContentDisposition = $"attachment; filename={nomeOriginal}"
        };

        if (paraDownload)
        {
            sasToken = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasPolicy, _sasHeader);
        }
        else
        {
            sasToken = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasPolicy);
        }

        return new Uri(blob.Uri, sasToken).AbsoluteUri;
    }



    public static CloudBlobContainer InstanciaContainer(string container)
    {
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ChaveStringConexao);
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(container);

        return blobContainer;
    }
```

**ConnectionString example for webconfig:**

```
<add name="AzureArmazenamento" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=*****;AccountKey=ZO78t1NKuiW32kKTBlm6bWRohREzYpmokpuFI4N**********************;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net" />
```

**Example usage:**

```
var cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureArmazenamento"].ConnectionString;
AzureUtilitario.ChaveStringConexao = cnn;

var url = AzureUtilitario.ObterUrlTemporaria(container, file.key, file.OriginalName, download);
```

**For upload you do not need anything different. The SAS issue addresses you in the return of the file:**

```
    public static bool Salvar(string container, string nomeBlob, byte[] arquivo)
    {
        var blockBlob = InstanciaContainer(container).GetBlockBlobReference(nomeBlob);

        blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = Path.GetExtension(nomeBlob).ConverteParaContentType();

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(arquivo))
        {
            blockBlob.UploadFromStream(stream);

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your inputs Leandro, your sample also gave me some ideas to how to make my code working.